# I dont understand why I am getting a fatal exception in my onChildClick method for my expandable list view

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an expandable list view however when I expand it and click on the child I get an error that reads

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.claritech.simsentinelmobile, PID: 22606
>                                                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ExpandableListConnector
>   cannot be cast to com.xera.deviceinsight.home.ExpandableListAdapter

This is the line that is throwing the error

```
 ExpandableListAdapter adapter = (ExpandableListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
```

and this is the entire method I am trying to use an adapter to retrieve an object(details about the clicked child from server using retrofit)

```
 private void load(View view)
   {

      expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
      prepareListData();
      listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
      expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
      expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            System.err.println("child clicked");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "child clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemClickedEvent(SensorInformationChildFragment.TAB_CALL));
            //ExpandableListAdapter adapter = (ExpandableListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            ExpandableListAdapter adapter = (ExpandableListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult d = (OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult) adapter.getChild(groupPosition,  childPosition);
            d.SensorID = d.SensorID;
            OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult deviceSensor = (OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult) adapter.getChild(groupPosition , childPosition);
            Object contact = adapter.getChild(groupPosition , childPosition);
           // OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult contact = listDataChild.get(groupPosition).getContacts().get(childPosition);
            //sensorID = deviceSensor.SensorID;
            //sensorID = contact.equals()

            ReportingGroup.get(childPosition);

            return true;
         }
      });
   }
```

This is the log

```
01-11 11:42:30.328 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile D/dalvikvm: threadid=1: detach (group=0x41816ce0)
01-11 11:42:30.328 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41816ce0)
01-11 11:42:30.328 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
01-11 11:42:30.329 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ExpandableListConnector cannot be cast to com.xera.deviceinsight.home.ExpandableListAdapter
01-11 11:42:30.329 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at com.xera.deviceinsight.home.CostCentreListFragment$1.onChildClick(CostCentreListFragment.java:88)
01-11 11:42:30.329 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:712)
01-11 11:42:30.330 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:651)
01-11 11:42:30.330 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
01-11 11:42:30.330 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
01-11 11:42:30.331 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-11 11:42:30.331 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-11 11:42:30.331 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-11 11:42:30.331 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
01-11 11:42:30.332 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 11:42:30.332 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-11 11:42:30.332 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
01-11 11:42:30.332 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
01-11 11:42:30.333 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 11:42:30.333 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
01-11 11:42:30.335 22606-22606/com.claritech.simsentinelmobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.claritech.simsentinelmobile, PID: 22606
                                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ExpandableListConnector cannot be cast to com.xera.deviceinsight.home.ExpandableListAdapter
                                                                                     at com.xera.deviceinsight.home.CostCentreListFragment$1.onChildClick(CostCentreListFragment.java:88)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:712)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:651)
                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add the logs.

Comment: Try with `parent.getExpandableListAdapter();` method

Comment: parent.getExpandableListAdapter(); doesnt do the job . I have added the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using fully qualified class name in the following statement, i.e. -

```
listAdapter = new com.xera.deviceinsight.home.ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

Comment: thanks @jaibatrik I also changed to `ExpandableListAdapter adapter ;
  adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(context);` and that seems to help me avoid the previous crash but now I get a null pointer exception on the getChild method below

Comment: On which line are you getting the Exception? You can debug which variable is null in that line.

Comment: that works thanks . Now I am trying to retreive the object , you will notice ` d.SensorID ` how can I improve that to make it work